# SQL: вычислить дату первого четверга года

Tags: sql

Вопрос из тренажера: https://sql-validator.ru/task/birthdays_3

Необходимо написать запрос, который выводит дату первого четверга августа года рождения клиента для всех клиентов в формате по умолчанию.

Насколько понимаю, ожидается использование функции `strftime`, но я что-то совсем в тупике(

Comment: СУБД нам предлагается угадать? А вообще вычесть из номера дня номер дня недели да прибавить чего нехватает для четверга..

Comment: насколько я понимаю, это SQLite - в тренажере даже чет не обозначено, я пока просто вникаю в тему. давайте без пассивной агрессии, пожалуйста) за идею спасибо

Comment: Господа телепаты, прекратите возмущаться, все недостающие детали постановки моей задачи вы обязаны угадать самостоятельно, без пассивной агрессии.

Comment: Забавная ссылка - сайт требует [websql](https://caniuse.com/?search=websql) - фичу, реализованную только в движке хрома, причём которую выпилят в будущем, но и здесь всунули рекламу яндекс-браузера )))))

Comment: *насколько я понимаю, это SQLite - в тренажере даже чет не обозначено* А выполнить `SELECT VERSION();`? уж чего проще вроде бы...

Comment: `SELECT VERSION();` попробовала выполнить в первую очередь, выдал ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое это сначала определить какой день недели приходится на 1 августа  и потом посмотреть сколько дне до четверга. Т.е. если 1 августа это понедельник, то четверг будет 4 августа.

По заданию, сначала нужно определить год - его можно получить из даты рождения клиента.:

```
YEAR(client_dob)
```

Потом надо собрать из получившегося года дату для первого августа

```
CONCAT(YEAR(client_dob), '-08-01')
```

Следующим шагом надо получить номер дня недели для этой даты

```
WEEKDAY(CONCAT(YEAR(client_dob), '-08-01'))
```

Функция WEEKDAY возвращает 0 для понедельника и 6 для воскресенья.

Дальше надо вычислить дату на которую приходится четверг. Подобранная опытным путем формула может быть такой **((3 - x) + 7) % 7 + 1** где **x** это день недели на которое попадает первое число.  Если 1-ое число это четверг, то WEEKDAY вернет 3 и по  формуле результат будет 1 - т.е. первое число.
Если первое число это вторник (x = 1), то четверг будет третьим. По формуле получается 3. И возьмем случай когда 1-ое число это суббота (x = 5) и тогда первый четверг это 6-ое число. Считаем по формуле - получаем 6.

Если подставить выражение в формулу, то в результате будет вывод даты в интервале от 1 до 7.

```
(((3 - WEEKDAY(CONCAT(YEAR(client_dob), '-08-01'))) + 7) % 7 + 1)
```

А дальше осталось только собрать дату, зная год и число месяца

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(client_dob), '-08-0', (((3 - WEEKDAY(CONCAT(YEAR(client_dob), '-08-01'))) + 7) % 7 + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

СУБД угадана как SQLite

```
select birthday, DATE(STRFTIME('%Y-08-01',birthday),'+' || ((10-STRFTIME('%w',datetime(STRFTIME('%Y-08-01',birthday))))%7+1) ||' days') as date from table1
```

```
birthday    date
2023-07-07  2023-08-03
2022-05-02  2022-08-04
2015-04-03  2015-08-06
```

[Демо](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/67eda4/24)

Answer (score 0):

Короткое решение задачи

```
select DATE(STRFTIME('%Y-08-%d',(STRFTIME('%Y-08-01',BIRTH_DT)), 'weekday 4'))
```